# Extract an element inside an array that is inside a json object using jsonlogic

Tags: arrays, json, jsonlogic

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "transactionId" : "123456789",
    "amount" : 215,
    "refunds" : {
       "detail" : [
           {
               "id" : 12345,
               "amount" : 7
           },
           {
               "id" : 67890,
               "amount" : 15
           }
       ],
       "total_amount" : 22
   }
}
```

I need to extract the information from the refunds node, where the `id = 12345` using only jsonlogic.

Exploring the operations supported by jsonlogic, I found that it has an operation for arrays called `filter` ([link](https://jsonlogic.com/operations.html#map-reduce-and-filter)), but I have only found examples for arrays of basic data types (int, string, etc) but not for arrays of objects.

Does anyone have any idea how it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing different tests I found out that it is possible to filter this information using the `filter` operation.

the filter is as follows:

```
{"filter":[{"var":"refunds.detail"},{"==":[{"var":".id"},"12345"]}]}
```

the crucial part is to add before the field to filter the character `"."`